# Error while trying to create generic method to get the core service client

Tags: core-service

I am trying to to write a generic class CoreServiceSession to get the different type of client like CoreService or SessionAware. Below is my code:

```
 public class CoreServiceSession<T> : IDisposable
        where T : CoreServiceClient,SessionAwareCoreServiceClient
    {

        private T _client;

        public T CoreServiceClient
        {
            get { return _client; }
        }

        public CoreServiceSession(string endPoint, NetworkCredential credentials, ClientType clientType)
        {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                InitializeClient(endPoint, credentials, clientType);
            }
        }


        private void InitializeClient(string endPoint, NetworkCredential credentials, ClientType clientType)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (clientType)
                {
                    case ClientType.CoreServiceClient:
                        _client = (T)new CoreServiceClient(endPoint);
                        break;
                    case ClientType.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient:
                        _client = (T)new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(endPoint);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                    _client.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials;

            }

            catch (EndpointNotFoundException e) { }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            }
}
```

However I am getting Compile Time error saying "Cannnot convert to SessionAwareCoreServiceClient to T. Can I get any help here? And also If I reverse the position of client Type in constraint "where T : CoreServiceClient,SessionAwareCoreServiceClient " then it start giving the same error for CoreServiceClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per c# specs here `T : CoreServiceClient,SessionAwareCoreServiceClient` is incorrect,  You can have only one class at start or/and followed by multiple interfaces Multiple classes are not allowed here. so you can change the code accordingly.